# How to convert date format in java?

Tags: java, html, date, jsoup

I have a String `a ="   December 2011   ";` 
There is a `&nbsp;` before and after it.
How can I Convert it to: `String b = "2011-12-1"`

Comment: C'mon man at least ***search*** on this site before posting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use this code.It gives whatever you want to output.
You first remove &nbsp using replace function and after you have to just parse the your string.

```
 try {
                String a = "&nbsp;December 2011&nbsp;";
                a = a.replace("&nbsp;", "");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy");
                SimpleDateFormat SdfParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                String date =SdfParser.format(sdf.parse(a)); 
                System.out.println(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is really all there is to it, use `.replace()`:

```
String b = a.replace("&nbsp;", "");
```

Unlike what its name would let you believe since `.replaceAll()` exists, `.replace()` will actually replace *all* occurrences. The difference is that `.replaceAll()` expects a string which will be compiled as a `Pattern` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`.

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy").parse(str));`

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "&nbsp;Dezember 2011&nbsp;";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy");

a = a.replace("&nbsp;", "");

Date parse = sdf.parse(a);
SimpleDateFormat outSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
String out = outSdf.format(parse);
System.out.println(out);
```